# Retrieve tables based on its contents in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to retrieve all tables and the associated column values where two of their specific columns (the column names will be passed into) that don't have the exact same content in them.

Here's a more definite break-down of the problem. Suppose, the columns that I need to look into is 'Column_1' and 'Column_2'

- First identify from in INFORMATION_SCHEMA which of the tables have both of these columns present in them(possible one sub-query),
- And then identify which of these tables don't have exact same content on these 2 columns meaning Column_1 != Column_2.

The following section would retrieve all the tables that has both 'Column_1' and 'Column_2'.

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE
    T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'myDB' AND
    T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE
            C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
            C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
            C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_1')
    AND EXISTS
    (
    SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE
            C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
            C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
            C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_2')
```

As the next step, I tried to use this as a sub-query and have the following at the end but that doesn't work and sql-server returns 'Cannot call methods on sysname'. What would the next step on this? This problem assumes all columns has the exact same Data-type.

```
WHERE SUBQUERY.TABLE_NAME.Column_1 != SUBQUERY.TABLE_NAME.Column_2
```

This is what's expected :

| Table_Name | Column_Name1 | Column_Value_1 | Column_Name2 | Column_Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table_A | Column_1 | abcd | Column_2 | abcde |
| Table_A | Column_1 | qwerty | Column_2 | qwert |
| Table_A | Column_1 | abcde | Column_2 | eabcde |
| Table_B | Column_1 | zxcv | Column_2 | zxcde |
| Table_C | Column_1 | asdfgh | Column_2 | asdfghy |
| Table_C | Column_1 | aaaa | Column_2 | bbbb |

Comment: Firstly please create a [mre] which illustrates what you are trying to accomplish, with sample data and desired results. Secondly, your sub-query returns the name of the table, a name is a string. SQL Server is not an object orientated database, you can't then reference columns off the table name. You need to build another query to get the columns from the table name.

Comment: You seriously want to query every record in your database to compare lengths of columns? Wow... interesting requirement.

Comment: @Dale K, thank you for all the suggestions. I modified my question as much as I can and removed any images.

Comment: @Dale K, this sounds a bit ridiculous, but unfortunately that's what I had been trying to accomplish to find potential bugs in a large database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in fact you want to actually compare values (not length) between two columns in tables that contain those two columns, you will need to generate dynamic SQL and then execute it. This could be done semi-automatically with the following:

```
DECLARE @SqlTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) =
    'UNION ALL'
    + ' SELECT Table_Name = <TNAME>'
    + ', Column_Name1 = <C1NAME>, Column_Value_1 = <C1>'
    + ', Column_Name2 = <C2NAME>, Column_Value_2 = <C2>'
    + ' FROM <T>'
    + ' WHERE ISNULL(<C1>, '(null)') <> ISNULL(<C2>, '(null)')'

SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
    , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        @SqlTemplate
        , '<TNAME>', QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME, ''''))
        , '<C1NAME>', QUOTENAME(C1.COLUMN_NAME, ''''))
        , '<C2NAME>', QUOTENAME(C2.COLUMN_NAME, ''''))
        , '<T>', QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME))
        , '<C1>', QUOTENAME(C1.COLUMN_NAME))
        , '<C2>', QUOTENAME(C2.COLUMN_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
    ON C1.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND C1.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND C1.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_1'
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
    ON C2.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND C2.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND C2.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_2'
WHERE T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'myDB'
AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

This would generate sql for each qualifying table of the form:

```
UNION ALL SELECT Table_Name = 'dbo.Z', Column_Name1 = 'X', Column_Value_1 = [X], Column_Name2 = 'Y', Column_Value_2 = [Y] FROM [dbo].[Z] WHERE ISNULL([X], '(null)') <> ISNULL([Y], '(null)')
```

After running the above, you would then cut & paste the generated SQL into another query window, remove the initial 'UNION ALL', and then execute the remaining SQL to get the final results.

There are ways of combining all the SQL into a single string and executing it automatically, but your problem sounds like a one-off process that doesn't warrant the extra complexity.

Comment: @T N, I probably have made it confusing by using Len in my initial post. Turns out I can ignore the length, but have to perform comparison on the actual content

Comment: @T N, I've used the modified version of the query, but the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH doesn't seem to work. While I understand what you're suggesting by building a dynamic query (and yes it's just a one off query and time complexity isn't a concern for me), but the above query doesn't seem to returning anything.
I can, however, confirm that the database I am working with, has a very large number of data where Column_1 != Column_2

Comment: Since you are interested in comparing values instead of lengths, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH should no longer be part of the query. My last post (made in haste) still included the LEN() function in the SQL template. I've edited the above to combine the prior addendum edit into the main post and changed the LEN() compare to a value compare. This should be pretty close to what I believe you are asking for. When you say that "the above query doesn't seem to returning anything", are you referring to the original SQL generator, or execution of the cut & pasted generated SQL.

Comment: @SaberTooth - I've added a few tweaks. Try it now. If you are not getting your desired results, you may need to do some debugging from your end.

Comment: @T N, I've found the issue that was causing the query not to work. In the second 'Join', it has to be AND C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_2', instead of C1. Thanks a lot once again for your help and I'm more than happy to accept this as my answer, once this small change is made to your suggested comment!

Comment: You're welcome. I fixed the bug you pointed out in the above post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to compare the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH or CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH metadata values in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table instead of using LEN(). This can be done using something like:

```
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
    , C1.COLUMN_NAME, C1.DATA_TYPE, C1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    , C2.COLUMN_NAME, C2.DATA_TYPE, C2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
    ON C1.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND C1.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND C1.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_1'
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
    ON C2.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND C2.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND C2.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_2'
WHERE T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'myDB'
AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND C1.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <> C2.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
```

The inner joins both limit results to tables having both columns and retrieve the column metadata. The length compare at the end checks for a mismatch.

This assumes character types. You might also want to check DATA_TYPE consistency ("char" vs "varchar" vs "nvarchar") or some of the other precision and scale values for other non-character data types.

Comment: @T N, sorry let me clarify a little more. The max-length would return how many characters the column will hold and this can definitely be returned from the Information_Schema. However, I want to query on the content of the column instead (the actual number of characters in the column) and retrieve the column name and the associated data in it. I've provided a sample output that the query may produce.

Answer (score 0):

To query the data within the columns you need dynamic SQL. I would advise you not to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (which is for compatibility only) and instead use `sys.tables` etc. You don't need to check `sys.columns` twice, you can use aggregation in the `EXISTS` subquery to check for multiple columns.

To compare the columns, you can do `Column_1 <> Column_2`, but that will not deal with nulls correctly. If the columns can be nullable then you should instead use the syntax shown in the code below: `NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column_1 INTERSECT SELECT Column_2)`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT
  STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT 
  Table_Name = ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ',
  Column_1,
  Column_2
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Column_1 INTERSECT SELECT Column_2)
'  AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
' )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
  AND s.name = 'myDB'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
      AND c.name IN ('Column_1', 'Column_2')
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT c.system_type_id) = 1  -- all same type
);

PRINT @sql;     -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```